# How do you get @Recomended to work in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can get`@recommended:workspace` extensions to work correctly but I am unsure as to why I cannot get the general `@recommended` to show anything.  Where am I supposed to put the `extensions.json` file?

My goal here is to have PowerShell install VSCode, copy over some JSON files for specific settings and then have the user shown the companies recommended extensions to install once they open up VSCode.

I know I can force them installed with `code --install-extensions` but I want the user to be able to pick and choose from the companies recommended list based on what kind of files they'll be working on.  What I can't seem to figure out is how to get that list to show except within a workspace.

For example, we have a Chef team, an Azure team, Linux team, etc. each needing different extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@recommended` option has no config. VS Code decides which extension to recommend based on the file types that exists in the folder/workspace that you opened ([official release info](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_search-for-an-extension)).

So, in your scenario, I guess the best option is to use Workspace Recommendations (`@recommended:workspace`), using a different recommendation for each team/project.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Alefragnani.  Not what I was hoping for but it is what it is.  :)